# Questions when moving from MbUnit to MsTest

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, factory, mbunit

Our team is looking to switch from using mbunit to mstest, but there appears to be some disconnect between the two.

Does anyone know how to simulate the CombinatorialTest and Factory attributes from mbunit when using mstest?

I think that is our only stumbling block before doing the switch.

Comment: Why the hell would you want to move from a good rich test framework to a rather limited one is the real question.

Comment: @craigb, the CodedUI library would be one strong reason ...

Comment: in theory it is possible to extend MsTest attributes. If you succeed at any of it, then I would love to know how you did it. http://mstestextensions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you basically need to write a test method that generates all of the combinations (or calls the factory and iterates through the items) that calls your original test (now no longer a test method) a bunch of times.

Unfortunately, these do not show up as individual tests in results - they show up as just one test- so you have to pretty explicit in your error output. This means that as with this approach, as soon as one fails it stops the rest (you can get around this by keeping a big list of results, but that's yet more overhead)

I'd think twice before going to mstest right now unless you have to - the lack of a test runner on a clean machine is killer, and it's neither extensible nor frequently updated.